# "While" asynchrone for API Call in node.js

Tags: node.js, api, while-loop, callback, promise

I have this issue I can't resolve :

I make an API call and it returns me two things :
-first part I want to keep : data
-second part that indicates me than the answer is not complete and a new URL to request to have the next part of the data

If the second part is not null, I have to do another call.
At the end, I need to save all the data of every API call.

I tried some recursive/callbacks/promises solutions but I don't have a functional solution.
Thank you for your help

Comment: Well, a recursive approach with either callbacks or promises is the way to go. But we cannot help you if you don't post the code that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```js
'use strict';

(async function main() {
  try {
    const data = [];
    let url = 'https://example.com';

    while (url) {
      const result = await asyncAPICall(url);
      data.push(result.data);
      url = result.nextURL;
    }

    processData(data);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})();
```